# Editing categories with Solspace Primary Category

Tags: solspace, categories

We're using the Solspace Primary Category add-on for a site and was wondering if it is possible with this add-on to let users add/edit categories via the Categories tab when publishing an entry, as per the default categories behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no. It's [an omission they're aware of](http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/9129/), but for the moment it's not available.